# deep link not opening application activity

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using below code to open my activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".home.AddConferenceActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_conference"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.ConferenceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="cokeconference.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/info"
                android:scheme="cokeconference" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and the URL is : cokeconference://cokeconference.com/info/Akshat/1234567891

I tried with both type of HTML files (with Java script as well) as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.location =      'cokeconference://cokeconference.com/info/Akshat/1234567891';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Base element example</TITLE>
   <a href="cokeconference://cokeconference.com/info/Akshat/1234567891"> Test     Conference Info </a>

</HEAD>
```

Where I am going wrong ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: try to use android:scheme="https" instead of android:scheme="cokeconference"

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do. and its working

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" /> // accept http and https
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="www.website.com" /> //your host
            <data android:path="/*" /> // detect any path with your host
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
<data
    android:host="cokeconference.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/info"
    android:scheme="cokeconference" />
```

With this:

```
<data android:scheme="cokeconference" />
<data android:host="cokeconference.com" />
<data android:pathPattern="/info/.*/.*" />
```